# Unable to filter elements from getRequest

Tags: angular, filter, get

A have found lots of similar topics, too many to list. I have tried them all but I keep getting error. I tried using map, I tried using pipe, I tried using filter, I've tried to combine them in every way possible. So please don't close it for a repost but show me how to solve it. I need to filter a get request and save the filtered list in an array. This is based on attribute status. The code is self explanatory. My last request is the one which I have the least uncompilable code. But it says: "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'". Whereas it is not about a void promise at all, I use an observable. Converting to Promise also didn't work.

service request:

```
  getAllTimesheets(): Observable<TimeSheet[]>{
    const url = environment.TIMESHEETSAPI_URL + "timesheets/findAll";
      return this.http.get<TimeSheet[]>(url);
  }
```

request in component.ts:

```
  timesheets!:TimeSheet[];

  getConfirmedSheet(): TimeSheet[]{
    return this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().forEach(sheets => sheets.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'CONFIRMED')).subscribe(sheets => this.timesheets = sheets);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **subscribe** to observable to make http request, in response you can filter anything you like.

```
getConfirmedSheet(): void {
  return this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().subscribe({next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {
    response.filter(...
  }});
}
```

Comment: Do I still need to add a subscribecode here behind the filter{}? Code compiles but I don't get any result this way

Comment: Just add console.log(response) and remove filter. Filter is an example. Response is your array, do everything you need with that.

Comment: this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().subscribe({next: (timesheetsConfirmed: TimeSheet[]) => {timesheetsConfirmed.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'CONFIRMED') }} ) ;     --> nothing comes tru now, though code compiles

Comment: what is expected output of your code? you just filter response without storing it anywhere. Does request work fine and you receive array of expected type in response?

Comment: it has to be stored in the array timesheets[], like what the original code did without the filter. Which is done by the subscribe, so I would assume it also happens here. Therefore my question, do I still have to add anything to the subscribe behind the filter?

Comment: Do it like this this.timesheets = timesheetsConfirmed.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'CONFIRMED'); It will store your filtered response in this.timesheets.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasted whole afternoon on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try that :
this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().pipe(filter(timeSheet => timeSheet.status == 'CONFIRMED' )).subscribe(timeSheets => {this.timesheets = timeSheets});

Comment: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'TimeSheet[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more